# When restarting a game, the falling objects do not restart at the slow speed, they continue to run faster

Tags: python, performance, pygame, reset

Go easy on me, I am a beginner: The "Press a Key to Play" on the Game Over screen doesn't always work and when it does, the TNT boxes falling are at an even faster speed. I need the tnt boxes to reset and start falling at a slow speed again like a new game.  I tried creating a mainLoop() function and putting most of my "loose" code (not already in a function) into the new function to call when Game Over so I could more easily reset, but my code would no longer work, so I took it out. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Below is my code

```
#Imports
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random, time
from pygame import mixer`

#Initializing 
pygame.init()

#Setting up FPS 
FPS = 60
FramePerSec = pygame.time.Clock()

#Creating colors
BLUE        = (0, 0, 255)
RED         = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN       = (0, 255, 0)
DARKGREEN  = (21,  89, 30)
BLACK       = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE       = (255, 255, 255)
ORANGE      = (255, 204, 51)
GRAY        = (185, 185, 185)

BORDERCOLOR = BLUE
BGCOLOR = DARKGREEN
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 36)
BIGFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 80) 
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
TEXTSHADOWCOLOR = GRAY

#Other Variables for use in the program
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1500
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
SPEED = 5

#Create a white screen 
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))

def showTextScreen(text):

    #Adding a new User event 
    INC_SPEED = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(INC_SPEED, 1000)
    pygame.display.update()

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    # This function displays large text in the
    # center of the screen until a key is pressed.
    # Draw the text drop shadow
    titleSurf, titleRect = makeTextObjs(text, BIGFONT, TEXTSHADOWCOLOR)
    titleRect.center = (int(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2), int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titleSurf, titleRect)

    # Draw the text
    titleSurf, titleRect = makeTextObjs(text, BIGFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    titleRect.center = (int(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - 3, int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - 3)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titleSurf, titleRect)

    # Draw the additional "Press a key to play." text.
    pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect = makeTextObjs('Press a key to play.', BASICFONT, TEXTCOLOR)
    pressKeyRect.center = (int(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2), int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + 100)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)
    pygame.display.flip()

    while checkForKeyPress() == None:
        pygame.display.update()
        FramePerSec.tick()

def makeTextObjs(text, font, color):
    surf = font.render(text, True, color)
    return surf, surf.get_rect()


def checkForKeyPress():
    # Grab KEYDOWN events to remove them from the event queue.
    checkForQuit()

    for event in pygame.event.get([KEYDOWN, KEYUP]):
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
         
            #Adding a new User event 
            INC_SPEED = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
            pygame.time.set_timer(INC_SPEED, 1000)
        
            continue
        return event.key
    return None

def checkForQuit():
    for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT): # get all the QUIT events
        terminate() # terminate if any QUIT events are present
    
    for event in pygame.event.get(KEYUP): # get all the KEYUP events
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate() # terminate if the KEYUP event was for the Esc key
        pygame.event.post(event) # put the other KEYUP event objects back

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


background = pygame.image.load("minecraftbackground.jpg").convert_alpha()
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (1500,800))
DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))
DISPLAYSURF.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()


pygame.display.set_caption("MacPhee Minecraft")
showTextScreen('MacPhee Minecraft')


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("TNT.jpg")
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(70,70))        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (random.randint(40,SCREEN_WIDTH-40), 0)    

    def move(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(0,SPEED)
        if (self.rect.top > 800):
            self.rect.top = 0
            self.rect.center = (random.randint(10, 1500), 0)
            pygame.display.update()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Steve4.png")
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(140,200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (260, 480)
    
   def move(self):
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
     
        if self.rect.left > 0:
            if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-55, 0)
        if self.rect.right < SCREEN_WIDTH:        
            if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(55, 0)

#Setting up Sprites        
P1 = Player()
E1 = Enemy()

#Creating Sprites Groups
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies.add(E1)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(P1)
all_sprites.add(E1)

#Adding a new User event 
INC_SPEED = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(INC_SPEED, 1000)

#Game Loop

while True:
   
    #Cycles through all events occuring  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == INC_SPEED:
            SPEED += 1
       
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # drawing background on the screen
    background = pygame.image.load("minecraftbackground.jpg").convert_alpha()
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (1500,800))
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

    #Moves and Re-draws all Sprites
    for entity in all_sprites:
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)
        entity.move()

    #To be run if collision occurs between Player and Enemy
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(P1, enemies):
           
        showTextScreen('Game Over')
        pygame.time.delay(5)


    pygame.display.flip()
    FramePerSec.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Variable values are not automatically reset in the interpreter when you run the game loop again. You should have a function that initializes everything to start values before entering the loop.

It would help significantly to put your loop in a function, then call the function from the global space. A common trope in Python is:

```
def RunGame():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RunGame()
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the reset, but now the TNT boxes won't speedup at all, tried moving around the INC_SPEED code and adding E1.move() but not working.  Any thoughts?
#Adding a new User event 
INC_SPEED = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(INC_SPEED, 1000)
 
def RunGame():
    SPEED = 5
    while True:       
        #Cycles through all events occuring
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == INC_SPEED:
                SPEED += 1
                E1.move()

Comment: Alas, it has been a long time since I have had pygame installed, so... I can’t play with it ATM. Make sure you have everything separated out into functions. Knowing _when_ events happen is the most important thing to grok.